# Transferred old SSD with OS to new laptop w/o clean install. Battery drains indredibly quickly

Tags: ssd, operating-systems, battery-life, transfer, fresh-install

So one of the main selling points of the laptop I just bought last week (Dell xps 13 9300) was its long battery life, allegedly 8hr on heavy use, or 13 hours light use, according to most benchmarks I saw. However, I realized it really only lasts 3-5 hours, which is not anything more than my 5 year old laptop.

[I'm including here a screenshot battery report I just generated directly from windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxh4I.png). [Here is the full report if it helps, in PDF.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13vYxm66p55vaD63kMeKtbQbWPgOOcwbq/view?usp=sharing)

I was wondering if this is normal. The specs are 16gb ram, i7 1065G, FHD **NOT 4k** Touch screen. I swapped the 256 NVMe SSD for my 512GB SATA SSD. I have it on dual boot with windows + an ubuntu/debian distro. Windows version is 10.0.19041, build 19041.

The only non-faulty reason I see for this would be that I swapped my old SSD with the one that came with this laptop without doing a clean install of windows, and even though I installed all the drivers/updated the BIOS maybe not doing the clean install hinders battery optimization?

I did indeed check and all my drivers/bios are up to date.

Comment: The old OS disk may have a CPU intensive virus - not unheard of. Try a new disk / new OS or a clean USB Boot OS and test that way.

Comment: @John my CPU is mostly under <45% per my task manager. Would such a virus not show up in there, under processes?

Comment: CPU should run <5% more than 95% of the time, so something is on the old disk using CPU.

Answer (score 1):

In order to verify that your new computer is operating properly, you need a fresh install of some operating system and measure that way.

You have used an old disk with an old operating system install and it is using 45% CPU which is a lot and which drags down your battery. That is why the battery is depleting quickly.

A properly working machine will normally have an average CPU load of 5% or less more than 95% of the time.

Try a new OS known to be free of problems.

Comment: I'll switch the SSD with the one that came with the laptop, which has Ubuntu installed, and benchmark the battery. That should be a very good indicator. I'll update this post with the result tomorrow.